# Strange behavior with matplotlib subplot animation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to animate a figure with subplot.
For that, I use this official example :

http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/subplots.html

Now, I would like have access to this feature through a function.
So, I replace the 3 last lines of this official example

```
ani = SubplotAnimation()
# ani.save('test_sub.mp4')
plt.show()
```

by :

```
def MyDraw():            
    ani = SubplotAnimation()
    plt.show()

MyDraw()
```

The official example works perfectly but calling this through the function `MyDraw` does not work. It produces no error message, but the figure show each axes with no curve inside...

If someone could help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please explain what means `through another function`? Can you provide its code?

Comment: I speak about the function MyDraw() as suggets in my post. I edit the post to clarify this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must keep a reference to the animation object or it (along with it's timers which update the plot) get garbage collected.

See http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#animation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot tacaswell for your help.

So, the solution is to keep a reference to the animation object like that:

```
def MyDraw():            
    ani = SubplotAnimation()
    plt.show()
    return ani

ani=MyDraw()
```

even if you have no need to deal with the variable `ani` thereafter.

Note also that

```
ani = SubplotAnimation()
plt.show()
```

works fine, but

```
SubplotAnimation()
plt.show()
```

does not work, for exactly the same reason.